# Using JavaScript + Selenium WebDriver to automate testing

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

Is it possible to automate testing using **JavaScript + Selenium**?

Since I don’t know Java, Python and C #, but I know Front-End.

Does anyone have any experience? Is it difficult / 
realizable? Are there any best practices?

At least take it all, given that at the moment JS has gained immense popularity

Comment: [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) Automation tool for angular is deep down based on these two.

Comment: Aa far as I know it works well with Javascript, but we had issues as soon as Angular was involved. If you only have standard Javascript you should not have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does in fact have Javascript bindings, it can be downloaded here: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ (Current version as of posting is 4.0.0-alpha.1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are JS savvy, you can use [Cypress.io](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress.html#Who-uses-Cypress). It is a UI end-to-end testing framework that has its own mechanism for manipulation DOM in the browser. By running directly in the browser Cypress has access to everything in the browser, including your application under test. It seems to work well for building web applications using modern JavaScript frameworks.

There is a comparison of Selenium with Cypress [here](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/blog/test-automation/selenium-vs-cypress/). Cypress tests are written using Mocha and Chai, so the syntax should be understandable to most Javascript users, and it is very developer-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to automate using selenium and javascript.

### Installing Selenium

> To get started, make sure you have Selenium’s language bindings for
>   Javascript installed and ready. You can find the official resource for
>   this here:
>
> http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

### Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings

**Javascript (Node) 4.0.0-alpha.1    2018-01-13 :**

https://npmjs.org/package/selenium-webdriver

**Official selenium javascript documentation:**

> https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Selenium Official Webpage](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), [Download Section](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/), you can see in the **Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings** section the following are listed :

1. *Java*
2. *C#*
3. *Ruby*
4. *Python*
5. *Javascript (Node)*

So from my personal take would be, these 5 variants which are the most widely used *Selenium Clients* while dealing with *Automation Framework* with *Selenium*

---

### Documentation

Leaving aside Selinium's GitHub ducumentation, its pretty clear majority of the documentation available on internet is on *Selenium (Java)*. It's because of *Java*'s world wide popularity as a *Language*. So learning becomes easier.
Even the frequency of *Selenium (Java) Client Releases* would support my native view.

But, personally I have found *Selinium's GitHub Documentation* for all the client bindings are perfect and precise.

---

### [Selenium-Javascript (Node)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html)

To use *Selenium* to for any task that requires automating interaction with the browser using *Javascript (Node)* **Selenium** may be installed via `npm` with:

```
npm install selenium-webdriver
```

You will need to download additional components to work with each of the major browsers. The drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft's IE and Edge web browsers are all standalone executables that should be placed on your system PATH. Apple's safaridriver is shipped with Safari 10 for OS X El Capitan and macOS Sierra. You will need to enable Remote Automation in the Develop menu of Safari 10 before testing.

An example:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q'));.sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```